# TypeError: stub expected to yield, but no callback was passed

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sinon

I'm in the process of migrating some mysql DB from one major version to the next and I have several nodejs projects that uses them. In order to make those projects work with the new mysql version, I had to upgrade the mysql2 dependency (and the node version).
I have a mysql healthcheck that was not running under this new version of mysql2:

```
const check = {
  mysql: client =>
    cb => client.query('SELECT 1+1 AS result', error => cb(null, {
      success: !error,
      details: { error },
    }))
}
```

Error was `Callback function is not available with promise clients.`

I updated the code to look like this:

```
const check = {
  mysql: client =>
    cb => client.query('SELECT 1+1 AS result')
      .then(_ => {
        cb(null, {
          success: true,
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        cb(null, {
          success: !err,
          details: { err },
        })})
}
```

I don't know if that actually fixes the healthcheck, but it sure did break the test:

```
it('should return when client does not returns an err', (done) => {
      const fakeClient = { query: sinon.stub().yieldsAsync(null) };

      const mysqlCheck = check.mysql(fakeClient);

      mysqlCheck((err, report) => {
        expect(fakeClient.query).calledWith('SELECT 1+1 AS result');

        expect(err).not.to.exist;
        expect(report.success).to.be.true;
        expect(report.details.error).to.not.exist;
        done();
      });
    });
```

Error is the following:
`TypeError: stub expected to yield, but no callback was passed. Received [SELECT 1+1 AS result]`

I've tried tinkering with the test but I don't know much about nodejs and I'm not even sure I understand what the issue is.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**
I've updated my stub to look like this, thanks to @Bergi:

```
const fakeClient = { query: () => Promise.resolve() };
sinon.stub(fakeClient, 'query').resolves().callsFake(() => {
  return Promise.resolve({
    success: true
  });
});
```

Test is passing but I'm getting warnings:
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): AssertionError: expected false to be true`

Can I safely ignore them or should I do something about them?

Comment: Don't use `yieldsAsync` but a stub that returns a promise

Comment: OK thanks, I think I've managed to do that but I'm getting a warning now (although test is passing). What can I do about it? 

I updated my post to reflect the changes

Answer (score 1):

Example:

`check.js`:

```js
const check = {
  mysql: client =>
    cb => client.query('SELECT 1+1 AS result')
      .then(_ => {
        cb(null, {
          success: true,
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        cb(null, {
          success: !err,
          details: { err },
        })
      })
}

module.exports = { check }
```

`check.test.js`:

```js
const sinon = require('sinon');
const { check } = require('./check');

describe('76045264', () => {
  it('should return when client does not returns an err', (done) => {
    const fakeClient = { query: sinon.stub().resolves() };
    const mysqlCheck = check.mysql(fakeClient);

    mysqlCheck((err, report) => {
      sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(fakeClient.query, 'SELECT 1+1 AS result')
      sinon.assert.match(report, { success: true })
      sinon.assert.match(err, null)
      done();
    });
  });
})
```

Test result

```bash
  76045264
    ✓ should return when client does not returns an err


  1 passing (13ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |   83.33 |      100 |      75 |      80 |                   
 check.js |   83.33 |      100 |      75 |      80 | 10                
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

package version: `"sinon": "^8.1.1"`